# .NET 8 API keeps trying to use old connection string

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have recently deployed a new .NET 8 API running on IIS using a SQL database. I've set up a SQL login for the API and tested the credentials; updated appsettings.json to reflect the new connection. However, when I try to access the login end point, I receive a 500 error, event log indicating that the API is trying to access SQL as the app pool user as if it has the old connection string somewhere because on my dev machine, it uses integrated security. I have tried:

- Cleaning the solution, completely deleting the API from the production environment, and redeploying
- Double checking that the connection string is the same in every variation of appsettings.json to rule out that it is not getting it from one of them.
- Restarting the app pool, restarting the site, setting up a new site for the API.
- Searching through the code for anywhere it may have the old one stored
- Including the correct connection string as the default connection in the publish settings
- Applying the connection string in the web.config

The SQL instance is sitting on the same server as the API:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MainConnection": "Server=.;Database=MyDatabase;user id=API_DatabaseUser;password=api_password;Trusted_Connection=True;encrypt=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "JWT": {
    "ValidAudience": "REDACTED",
    "ValidIssuer": "REDACTED",
    "Secret": "REDACTED"
  }
}
```

[image: Publish Settings]

I want to understand why and where the old connection string is being used and why the new connection string in appsettings.json is being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by changing Trusted_Connection to false.